# Pointing sub-domain to another domain on another host

Tags: dns

I have 2 domains and 2 hosting packages.

What I want:
`status.domainA.example` to `domainB.example/status`. I want that `status.domainA.example` is in the address bar.

What I tried:
I've set a `CNAME` record:
`status.domainA.example` to `domainB.example`. `domainB.example/status` appeared. It was in the address bar. Further, before you can open it, you need to allow wrong-configured SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to do the following -

1. On the host where `domainB.example` is hosted, add a virtual host for `status.domainA.example` and point `/status` to the appropriate files.
2. Add `CNAME` entry of `status.domainA.example` pointing to `domainB.example`

Alternate Way - Use a reverse proxy server or if using cloudflare of AWS use  javascript workers (http://cloudflareworkers.com  or AWS lambda)

1. Point `status.domainA.example` to a worker.
2. Add code in the worker to fetch the response from `domainB.example/status` and send the response.

If using as reverse proxy -

1. Setup a reverse proxy server eg. nginx or any other.
2. point `status.domainA.example` to the reverse proxy server.
3. Add config to set `domainB.example` as backend of reverse proxy server.

You can refer to internet for details about how to setup reverse proxy server. - https://www.techandme.se/set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy/

If you have access to only file hosted on `status.domainA.example` than you can simply make a curl call to `domainB.example/status` and print the output.

Decide your approach

Comment: I'm on a shared host with SSH access. I can't add virtual hosts. Further, I can't write code on the host of domainA.com. When the hosting from that one is down, it has to be possible to head to the status page.

Comment: You can do the alternate approach of reverse proxy. Add code for fetching domainB.com/status and respond on status.domainA.com.

Comment: I've no access to resources like nginx. I can only use composer and have access to files. That's all what I can.

Comment: updated answer - If you have access to only file hosted on `status.domainA.com` than you can simply make a curl call to `domainB.com/status` and print the output.

Comment: I've seen that I've access to cURL. But, now the next step: How to do that? I'm not experienced with cURL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185442/discussion-between-chris-van-chip-and-mdeora).